# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I currently use this code to redirect HTTP to HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

It's working, http://website.com gets redirected to https://website.com,
however when I'm not on the website and try to go https://website.com/about or https://website.com/contact I get redirected to https://website.com/index.php

I can only visit /pages when I'm already on the website.
How to fix this?
I tried several .htaccess scripts but none worked.

Try to click http://ndvibes.com/about you'll get redirected to index.php if you're not already on the website.
How to fix? Thanks!

Comment: I clicked the link and I am not getting redirected to the index page, it keeps me on the about page.

Comment: @MinistryofChaps I just applied MinistryOfChap's solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work better.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No, it's redirecting to HTTPS but still the same problem occurs.

Comment: Your answer worked, I had to clear my cache. Thanks! ;)

Comment: Great, if it's worked feel free to click it as the correct answer so others can see the solution.