# Redirect http to https in .htaccess (Symfony 4)

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, cpanel, symfony4

I'm trying to host my symfony 4 website in a shared hosting (Cpanel), and i want to redirect http to https automatically.

I found on many questions here is that i should change mu .htaccess, here is my current .htaccess content :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

AddType application/x-lsphp72 .php

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

I found on this question [Redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483830/redirect-http-to-https) that i should add :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but i got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT error.

Any of you guys got the same thing as me ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483830/redirect-http-to-https)

Comment: i got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT error by adding this :/

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase i tried this : RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: and this too: access_control:
     - { path: ^/my-path, requires_channel: https }

Comment: in both i got TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue via `security.yaml`

```
 access_control:
     - { path: ^/my-path, requires_channel: https }
```

now when I access to http://my-website.com/my-path automatically I am redirected to https

Comment: I just tried this, but the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT error shows up again

Comment: Hi, I followed this guide: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html and I had no problem with https redirect. So the problem should be in your .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the `.htaccess`, I would suggest to modify the virtual host
(config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`)

Do this and you're set :

```
# Catch and redirect all http
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName example.com

    # Rest of your vhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Actually there is no apache2 folder inside the /etc folder

Comment: Working in the vhost is a good idea - but how should this work for deep links that do include any path?

Comment: The current example redirect everything after `/`. So, if your url is `http://example.com/page/1?v=2` then it will redirect to  `https://example.com/page/1?v=2`

Comment: @AdnaneLamghari are you using nginx? If so, the same method exists, in nginx syntax that is.

Comment: @Preciel no i'm not using it :/